# Indentar al tocar enter

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Lo que quiero lograr es que al declarar un metodo, loop, if etc y colocar las 2 llaves {}, al tocar ente se indente automaticamente quedando con las convenciones de c#.

```
If(ejemplo)
{

}
```

Comment: Instalate codemaid

Comment: Otra opción es pulsar la combinación de teclas ctrl+K ctrl+d. Esto hace que indente todo el codigo correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Opción 1**

Para formatar el texto seleccionado: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Para formatar el documento: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Te recomiendo ver tambien los [atajos de teclado predefinidos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/da5kh0wa(v=vs.100)). (Estos dos son `Edit.FormatSelection` y `Edit.FormatDocument`.)

[Enlace respuesta de SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755942/how-do-you-auto-format-code-in-visual-studio)

---

**Opción 2**

Otra solución es conocer todos los atajos de las instrucciones que vayas picando en el código los cuales se ejecutan escribiendo la `[palabra clave]` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Ejemplo:

`for` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> escribe lo siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

}
```

Puedes ver la lista de atajos de teclado en la siguiente página, incluso te explica cómo crear nuevos: [enlace](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tricks-and-shortcuts-to-use-visual-studio-like-a-pro-double-your-code-speed/).

Answer (score 4):

- Herramientas-> Opciones-> Editor de texto -> C# -> Tabulaciones -> Inteligente
- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs. Identing: Smart (si VS está configurado en inglés)

Comment: Yo no conocía esta opción la verdad. Muy buena respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno escribe el comando y presiona 2 veces la tecla `TAB`

`if` + `tab` + `tab`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`while` + `tab` + `tab`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`for` + `tab` + `tab`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]